# How to calculate intersection points based on corners and number of cells

Tags: java, opencv, android

I am trying to find all intersection points (their x and y values) based on 4 corner points that I always have and number of cells (in my case 9, so 9x9 matrix, sudoku puzzle).

My 4 corners are marked with green cross, and taged P1 to P4. 
I tried to calculate it, and only managed to do it precisely for the first row.

```
double xDis = p2.x - p1.x;
double yDis = p2.y - p1.y;
double xW = xDis / 9;
double yH = yDis / 9;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Point point = new Point(p1.x + (i * xW), p1.y + (i * yH));
}
```

This code would work exactly as I expected it but only for the first row.
What am I missing here ? Is there some kind of algoritmh that already does this ? Any hints are welcome.
Note that I am using android with OpenCV library.

[image: points]

Comment: You forgot about the second dimension when iterating... there are 100 intersections, you only calculated 10 of them.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but I am not sure how to calculate x,y possitions for them.

Comment: Add inner `for` loop that using`j` and change the point calculation to be `Point(p1.x + (i * xW), p1.y + (j * yH))`... so that `i` means the `x` axis offset in squares, and `j` means the `y` axis offset in squares.

Comment: Tried it, does not work. All of the points with this same angle of the puzzle are stacked somewhere from P1 towards P4, and nowhere near P2 and P3

Comment: I'll write up a full example when I get home later tonight. (don't have JDK here)

Comment: I ended up using your solution, but first warped the image so that I get rid of the angle and then its easy to cut it. tnx for help. You can write your answer here, I will accept it.

Comment: Good idea :) Now that I'm actually working this out, I realized I forgot something in my comments above as well.

Comment: To be honest, since you eventually need to recognize the digits in the squares, and that there's perspective distortion in your sample image, your approach with warping the image is the one to go with. The [code I have so far](https://pastebin.com/w53uX578) doesn't handle the distortion correctly, so at best I get [this sort of result](https://i.imgur.com/UlqeCQH.png). I could extend it with further math to deal with the distortions... but that seems like reinventing the wheel. I don't think this is worth writing up as an answer -- self-answer with your solution instead.

Comment: @DanMašek I ended up coming back to this problem, and found a nice solution. You can have a look at this commit if you are interested 
https://github.com/liliumbosniacum/realtime-sudoku-solver/commit/7f90f9326ce84d7f735a47c5743569a850b9ee66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written above in the comments, I ended up warping the image and then cutting it. It looks something like this

```
if (points != null) {
        Point p1 = points[0];
        Point p2 = points[1];
        Point p3 = points[2];
        Point p4 = points[3];

        MatOfPoint2f src = new MatOfPoint2f(
                p1,
                p2,
                p3,
                p4);

        drawMarker(frame, p1, new Scalar(255,0,0), 0, 20, 1);
        drawMarker(frame, p2, new Scalar(255,0,0), 0, 20, 1);
        drawMarker(frame, p3, new Scalar(255,0,0), 0, 20, 1);
        drawMarker(frame, p4, new Scalar(255,0,0), 0, 20, 1);

        double x = p2.x - p1.x;
        double y = p3.y - p2.y;

        MatOfPoint2f dst = new MatOfPoint2f(
                new Point(0, 0),
                new Point(x,0),
                new Point(0,y),
                new Point(x,y)
        );

        Mat warpMat = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst);
        //This is you new image as Mat
        Mat destImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(bw2, destImage, warpMat, new Size(x, y));

        List<Mat> cells = getCells(destImage, destImage.width() / 9, destImage.height / 9);


    }



private List<Mat> getCells(Mat m, int width, int height) {

    Size cellSize = new Size(width, height);
    List<Mat> cells = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            Rect rect = new Rect(new Point(col * width, row * height), cellSize);

            Mat digit = new Mat(m, rect).clone();
            cells.add(digit);
        }
    }

    return cells;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only do your calculation once, on the first row.

Put your for loop inside of another for loop and run it 10 times, and you should be good (Adding in whatever x,y translation happens as you traverse downwards in y).

As for if there is any automated way to do this, yes. I could suggest using [Harris Corner Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html). I suspect using the right thresholds could get you only the thicker line corners. You could also try doing line detection and looking for intersections.

Also, [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) article may be helpful if you find you aren't finding good lines/corners. You can correct the shading from the lighting and get a good clean image to analyze.

Comment: I tried it already like that but it just did not work. I already have correct corners all the time. Also I can detect lines and delete them (to extract digits), but I am not sure if it possible to get intersection points from lines Mat.